# How would I convert these formulas into VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a spreadsheet at work, the data from before and after testing is stored is the form 123abc456. I can't just simply use the left and right function i.e. Left(Data!A5,3) since the values can vary from 1 to 5 digit numbers. I heard that VBA was very good for this, however I am new to this coding language. So I would ideally like to be able to just call things like =LHS(Data!A5) and =RHS(Data!A5) to reduce the number of times I have to adjust the data cell I am referencing.

These are the excel functions I am currently using:

```
=LEFT(Data!A5,FIND("abc",Data!A5)-1)
=RIGHT(Data!A5,LEN(Data!A5)-FIND("abc",Data!A5))
```

I was attempting to use VBA to code the LHS, and this is my failed attempt at getting the LHS. Any advice or code on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Function LHS(CellRef As String)
Dim DataCell As String
DataCell = Worksheets("Data").Range(CellRef).Value
'abc is always the filler character
LHS = Left(DataCell, (Worksheets("Data").Range("A5").Find("abc") - 1))
End Function
```

This is my attempt, however, much to my confusion I get a #NAME? error when I run this.

Image of Code in VBA

[image: 1]

Image of name error with current code

[image: 2]

Comment: First of all, make sure that the code is in a regular code module.

Comment: You're looking for [`InStr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) in VBA, btw.

Comment: `Find()` in VBA is not the same as the worksheet `FIND()`  In VBA you want to look at `Instr()`

Comment: Re _to reduce the number of times I have to adjust the data cell I am referencing_.  VBA is not the only way to achieve that.  Eg `=LET(dat,      LEFT(dat, FIND("abc",dat) -1)`

Comment: Or use `Textbefore` and `TextAfter` functions

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious way to handle this in VBA is to use the [`InStr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function)-function. The function gets 4 parameters, but the first and the last are optional. The most common ways to use the function to find a string ("needle") in a larger string ("haystack") is either

```
InStr(hayStack, needle)
```

or

```
InStr(1, hayStack, needle, vbTextCompare)
```

Main difference is that the 2nd form can search Case-independent. It would, for example, locate the strings `"ABC"`, `"abc"` or `"Abc"` (or...).

The function returns the position of the first occurrence of *needle* (there is also a counterpart `InStrRev` that finds the last occurrence). If it was not found, the function returns 0.

Now your functions return either the part that is *left* from the needle using the `left`-function or the part that is *right* from the needle, which could be done either using the `right`-function, or using the `mid`-function.

The functions could look like this:

```
Public Function LHS(cellValue As String, Optional separator As String = "abc") As String
    Dim p As Long
    p = InStr(cellValue, separator)
    ' if you want to find also ABC or ABC, change the line to:
    ' p = InStr(1, cellValue, "abc", vbTextCompare)
    
    If p > 0 Then
        LHS = Left(cellValue, p - 1)
    End If
End Function

Public Function RHS(cellValue As String, Optional separator As String = "abc") As String
    Dim p As Long
    p = InStr(cellValue, separator)
    ' if you want to find also ABC or ABC, change the line to:
    ' p = InStr(1, cellValue, "abc", vbTextCompare)
    
    If p > 0 Then
        RHS = Mid(cellValue, p + Len(separator))
    End If
End Function
```

The functions need to be stored in a regular module, not in the workbook or worksheet module, else Excel will not find them (and you get the `#NAME?` error).

When you put a formula like `=LHS(Data!A5)` into a cell, Excel will pass the *value* of the cell into the function, so there is no need to think about cell references or the like. You could pass also a reference to the cell as parameter, but for most functions that are used as UDF, this is not needed.

Note that I added a 2nd, optional parameter to the functions. You could call them for example like `=LHS(Data!A5, "xyz")`, and now the function would look for "xyz" instead of "abc" - which makes it more flexible.

If the expected result is always a number and you want to use it as a number in Excel (123 is something different than "123"), you could change the function for example to

```
Public Function LHS(cellValue As String, Optional separator As String = "abc") As Long
    Dim p As Long
    p = InStr(cellValue, separator)
    If p > 0 Then
        LHS = Val(Left(cellValue, p - 1))
    End If
End Function
```

Hint: When using a function and there is an error inside the function, Excel will display `#Value!`. Then it's time for debugging, but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

For `LHS` you can simply use `Val` function, for `RHS` there is a bit longer way:

```
Function LHS(rng As Range)
        LHS = Val(rng.Value)
End Function
Function RHS(rng As Range)
       RHS = Val(Mid(rng.Value, InStr(rng.Value, "abc") + 3))
End Function
```

The arguments are references not text addresses, so you use it like `=LHS(Data!A5)` and `=RHS(Data!A5)`